# SQL Substitute hard-coding of Search/Replace strings in long Case Statement by using a Lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-update, case, teradata

I have a big table to be updated for matching strings.
current implementation uses case statement for matching multiple strings hardcoded in the case.

```
Sample table: 
Table1:
pagestring varchar(200),
subclass varchar(50),

update Table1
set subclass = case
                   when pagestring LIKE ANY ('index%','Store/%') THEN 'Home'
                   WHEN pagestring LIKE 'chair XX%' THEN 'chairXX'
                   WHEN pagestring LIKE 'chair %' THEN 'chair'
                   WHEN pagestring LIKE ANY ('account%','order%') THEN 'order' 
                   WHEN pagestring LIKE 'home/shop%' THEN 'shop'
                   WHEN pagestring LIKE 'chairleather%' THEN 'chairleather'
                   WHEN pagestring LIKE ANY('lamp%','light%') THEN 'light'
               end
```

Instead of hard code in case statement, i want to check if the search strings can be kept in a table and match with Table1 pagestring.

```
Table2
      seq byteint,
      searchstring varchar(100),
      searchlength integer,
      subclass varchar(50)

seq  searchstring    searchlength  subclass
---  --------------  ------------  -----------
  1  index             5           Home
  2  Store             5           Home
  3  chair XX          8           chairXX
  4  chair             5           chair
  5  account           7           order
  6  order             5           order
  7  home/shop         9           shop
  8  chairleather      12          chairleather
  9  lamp              4           light
 10  light             5           light
```

pagestring with 'chair XX' has to match before checking 'chair '

Comment: You should keep the CASE, you just might create it automatically based on a Select on Table2. I implemented similar loopup-CASEs using SQL UDFs which are recreated whenever there was an Insert/Update/Delete on the lookup table.

Comment: @dnoeth hi, i was looking for something without using UDF in my code

Comment: How often are going to run this update? There's no problem at all to use the existiing CASE, it's more efiicient than anything else.

Comment: @dnoeth actually this is part of a bigger procedure, which runs multiple times a day. I was looking for a different way to add or update the case conditions

Answer (score 0):

I understand Teradata has similar capabilities to DB2 with support for both regular expressions and the SQL MERGE statement. That being the case I've created an example DB2 fiddle using your sample table structures and data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=bd02f821ef3c5284257470a225064465).

```
MERGE INTO table1 AS tgt 
USING (SELECT pagestring, 
              t2.subclass 
       FROM   table1 T1, 
              table2 T2 
       WHERE  REGEXP_SIMILAR(pagestring, searchstring)) AS src 
ON src.pagestring = tgt.pagestring 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET tgt.subclass = src.subclass
```

For the 'chair XX' versus 'chair' situation, you need a special regular expression pattern 'chair (?!XX)' in the searchpattern field to identify instances of 'chair ' NOT followed by 'XX' (as you will see in the fiddle).  Using regular expressions will give you a lot more versatility in how you match patterns than you get from using LIKE/LIKE ANY.

EDIT: Swapped DB2 syntax `REGEXP_LIKE` with Teradata's equivalent `REGEXP_SIMILAR`.